# Create related record form on separate page with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have this model :

```
School hasMany Teachers
```

I have a view action/page on my School controller, where I need to put a "add new teacher for this school" link. This link must lead to the Teacher add page, and the new teacher must reference the school from the previous page.

I am doing this by adding a query string on my link, like :

```
<a href="/teachers/add?school_id=4">Add new teacher for this school</a>
```

Then in my TeachersController I pass this value to my view (teacher::add.ctp) as $school_id and create a hidden input in the add.ctp like :

```
$this->hidden('school_id', ['value' => $school_id])
```

So when I submit the teacher add form, its school_id field is set correctly.

Is there a better way to do this ? I am not really happy with my solution and the query string trick (one could change this in the address bar...).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess you'll have to pass the information to the action in some way.

Instead of a link you can use a form (cake FormHelper has a [formlink()](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-standalone-buttons-and-post-links)  method for this) and pass `school_id` via POST

Anyway even if you use POST data there are still many ways a user could modify the data.

The problem I see here is that you use an hidden field. I think it's redundant because when you send your data to `/teachers/add?school_id=4`you already have this information in your query data

so you can do

```
$teacher =  $this->Teachers->newEntity()
$teacher = $this->Teachers->patchEntity($teacher , $this->request->data);
$teacher->school_id = $this->request->query('teacher_id');
```

Comment: You're right I could get rid of my hidden input. I guess my problem is to keep some kind of context, so what about using the Session component to store and consume my school_id ? Would it be a cleaner way ? I could set it in my School::view action and consume it in my Teacher::add...

Comment: what happens if you open different schools in different browser tabs? The last opened tab saves in session the `schoold_id`. But if you then go to the first opened tab and click 'add teacher' you'll end adding the teacher to the last school.

Comment: bad idea indeed :)...even if in my use case this situation never happens.

Comment: you told you have a `/schools/view/4` page in wich you want to add a `/teachers/add/school_id=4` link. If so I guess you could always open a new tab and then go to `/schools/view/7`. If you have some kind of internal control to avoid this (i.e. a user can see just his own school but not other's) then use the same control to avoid adding teachers to other schools